# How to identify and control which CDN location serves my website?

Tags: dns, server, cdn

I have configured Akamai CDN for my site. I need to know which CDN location is used when I load my site.

Is it possible to specify the CDN location to use? Can we by-pass the Akamai CDN so that site will not be loading from CDN and will directly fetch site from servers?

Comment: you think they will provide the real time analytics about from which location transfered file

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use your browsers built in browser inspector to see the URL's which the content is being served from. If you then do a lookup on those URL's you'll be able to get an IP address of which you can find the geographical location of. I've not used Akamai before but it's also possible that the domain's they load content from (what your CNAME resolves to) may have geological name references in them.

Comment: yes we can find the CNAME for the host but it showing the CDN server in US. My question is when we load a site with CDN it will fetch the content from nearest CDN cluster where the end user is located. I am in india when we load the site it show that site is loading from US CDN server ip address. so how to find that nearest CDN server located at end users.